# dplyr if else statement

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I'm trying to write an if else statement based on precipitation type (snow, rain, mixed). I need to use corrections based on wind speed for when the precipitation is snow or mixed (i.e., correction factor for precipitation), but if it is rain, a correction factor does not need to be applied.

Here is the code I attempted to write for this:

```
  mutate(Precip_Corr = ifelse(
    PrecipType == "Snow", exp(-0.04*Wind_ms^1.75),
    PrecipType == "Mixed", 1.0104-(0.0562*Wind_ms)),
    Precip_Type == "Rain", Precip_mm)
```

Here is the df:

```
            date.time Air.Temp_F DewPtTemp_F  RH_. WindDir_DegfromN WindSp_knots HourlyPrecip_in HourlyPrecipT.in Precip_mm precip_cum_mm
1 2019-09-01 00:55:00       55.9          52 86.71                0            0               0            0.000     0.000         0.000
2 2019-09-01 01:55:00       61.0          54 77.72              310            3               T            0.005     0.127         0.127
3 2019-09-01 02:55:00       60.1          54 80.25                0            0               0            0.000     0.000         0.127
4 2019-09-01 03:55:00       57.9          54 86.82              170            5               0            0.000     0.000         0.127
5 2019-09-01 04:55:00       57.0        53.1 86.77                0            0               0            0.000     0.000         0.127
6 2019-09-01 05:33:00       57.9          54 86.82              260            4               0            0.000     0.000         0.127
  AirTemp_C PrecipType  Wind_ms
1  13.27778       Rain 0.000000
2  16.11111       Rain 1.543210
3  15.61111       Rain 0.000000
4  14.38889       Rain 2.572016
5  13.88889       Rain 0.000000
6  14.38889       Rain 2.057613
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Precip_Corr`.
x unused argument (1.0104 - (0.0562 * Wind_ms))
i Input `Precip_Corr` is `ifelse(...)`.
```

Comment: Can you use `dput()` on your df and post it here to create a Minimal Working Example for us?

Answer (score 0):

There are two error in your above code:

1. There is a bracket in the wrong place
2. As you are checking multiple conditions, you probably want `case_when` rather than `ifelse`.

As written your `ifelse` statement has a bracket in the wrong place:

```r
  mutate(Precip_Corr = ifelse(
    PrecipType == "Snow", exp(-0.04*Wind_ms^1.75),
    PrecipType == "Mixed", 1.0104-(0.0562*Wind_ms)), # this bracket closes the ifelse statement
    Precip_Type == "Rain", Precip_mm) # these are in the mutate, not the ifelse
```

Correcting this to:

```r
  mutate(Precip_Corr = ifelse(
    PrecipType == "Snow", exp(-0.04*Wind_ms^1.75),
    PrecipType == "Mixed", 1.0104-(0.0562*Wind_ms), # remove excess bracket
    Precip_Type == "Rain", Precip_mm)) # add moved bracket
```

However, after this correction there are too many arguments for `ifelse`:

- `ifelse` takes 3 arguments as follows: `ifelse(condition, value_if_yes, value_if_no)`
- You probably want `case_when` which takes any number of conditions `case_when(condition1 ~ value1, condition2 ~ value2, ... )`

So the code you are probably after is:

```r
  mutate(Precip_Corr = case_when(
    PrecipType == "Snow" ~ exp(-0.04*Wind_ms^1.75),
    PrecipType == "Mixed" ~ 1.0104-(0.0562*Wind_ms),
    Precip_Type == "Rain" ~ Precip_mm))
```

Note the use of `~` instead of commas in between the conditions and their values.